# How to change the Back button events at Fragment

Tags: android, onclicklistener, keylistener

[image]

When I click BACK button, I want to make the dialog dismiss. Like THIS:

[image]

But now, when I click back button, this app is exit! This is the method I found online, but it's not work!

```
mBaseView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    if (listAdapter.isShow) {
                        cancle();
                        return true;
                    }
                  }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's impossible to say with only that snippet of code. You could also override onBackPressed in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Exit Fest");
    alert.setMessage("Are you sure to exit the application?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("NO",new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog =alert.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Er, maybe I do not express clearly. The bottom "Cancel"/"Delete"/"Mark" is a LinearLayout in layout XML file. It's NOT a dialog. The function of Cancel() is just let the linearlayout not visible. When I click BACK button, I want call Cancel() to make that dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       yourdialog.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: ERROR:the method onkeydown(int keyevent) is undefined for the type fragment.